# IE10 and cookies encoding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, encoding, internet-explorer-10

If I create a cookie with the value 'ë' on the server, it becomes 'Ã«' when I read it on the client side.

This only occurs with IE (10). I don't get this issue with other browsers (Chrome and Firefox).

The way the cookie is created:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("test", "ë"));
```

Comment: what encoding are your page and header getting sent to the client with?

Comment: Have you specified the character encoding on the page which uses the cookie's value? For example, `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: yes, I've already added this meta tag with the value UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Per [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (sec. 4.2.2) and [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (sec. 2.2, 4.2), HTTP headers may only be transmitted in ISO-8859-1.  (There is an exception, but this is primarily used for MIME and is pretty much never seen in HTTP.)  Since ISO-8859-1 is really just a series of octets, the server can choose to use a different encoding (UTF8, in this case) if it wishes, since cookies are intended to be treated opaquely by the client anyway.  Thus it should be round-tripped correctly in all cases, but if the client tries *parsing* the cookie it will get different results based on whether or not it is following the RFCs.

Please try to avoid sending non-ASCII characters in headers if at all possible.  The HTTP spec never really accounted for this properly, and as a result it causes pain and heartache when used in practice. :(